# how to record the voip call using sipsorcery sdk?

Tags: sip, voip

I am using sample programs provided by sipsorcery: 
 https://github.com/sipsorcery/sipsorcery/tree/master/sipsorcery-softphonev2

What I want to record the call or record the part of one side spoken text, process it, then generate the answer test and speak it back.

What I need right now to process the spoken text. I wanted to record the parts of call and save them to a wav file and generate text from it. but it seems to me that I am doing wrong. I am not able to generate the correct wav file using the provided method of sipsorcery SDK.

I have tried to follow the example on this forum as well, but it didn't work

https://markheath.net/post/how-to-record-and-play-audio-at-same

I expect that this should work using a small temporary wave file at each time the user speaks a sentence and response back again playing back the processed response file.

Any guidance how can I achieve this sense of interception and processing of the call?

Thanks, 
Vivek

Answer (score 0):

This [example](https://github.com/sipsorcery/sipsorcery/tree/master/examples/UserAgentClient) should be pretty close to what you need. It plays the audio (only ulaw support) via the default speaker using NAudio. To record it should be a matter of switching from using NAudio playback to saving to a wav file.